# How to play Data type video using AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am trying to play a video after I download from remote using following code.

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(dataRepresentation: VideoService.instance.videoInfoArray[0].video, relativeTo: nil)!)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player
present(playerController, animated: true) {
player.play()
}
```

My VideoService class is a singleton class and video variable type is `Data()`. However when I try to play video with below code it is not working. How can I play video using data representative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [URL class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779865-init) the initializer `init?(dataRepresentation:relativeTo:isAbsolute:)` takes `Data` argument, yes, but that data is supposed to be an ASCII representation of an **URL string**, not the actual data you want to play.

What you need to do is save your video data to a file and use the file's URL to initialize `AVPlayer`

```
guard let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)?.first else { return }
url.appendPathComponent("video.mpeg") // or whatever extension the video is
VideoService.instance.videoInfoArray[0].video.write(to: url) // assuming video is of Data type
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
// other stuff with the player
```

To determine the reason why the player can't play your file, use [key-value observing of player's `status` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/responding_to_playback_state_changes). If you observe a change to `AVPlayer.Status.failed`, then you can check the player's `error` property to see the localized reason and error code.

```
var playerStatusContext = 0
player.addObserver(player, forKeyPath: "status", options: [.new, .initial], context: &playerStatusContext)

// (...)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                       of object: Any?,
                       change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                       context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    // Only handle observations for the playerItemContext
    guard context == &playerStatusContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                           of: object,
                           change: change,
                           context: context)
        return
    }

    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayer.status) {
        let status: AVPlayer.Status
        if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
            status = AVPlayer.Status(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
        } else {
            status = .unknown
        }

        if status == .failed {
            print(player.error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks now it is working, I was adding unnecessary file path but now it is ok. However, what if I'd like to save video into core data is it enough saving path into core data?